# Is it possible to patch a class instance with an existing Singleton instance?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, nosetests, python-unittest

I have a class representing our DB layer which is being instantiated internally in some classes (I cannot pass it as an outside parameter)
For example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dbapi = DatabaseAPI()
        self.timeout = 120

    def some_methods(self):
        pass
```

We're writing some Unit tests, and we'd like to mock the self.dbapi with an existing instance which we'll be creating before the test runs.

for example:

```
my_dbapi = DatabaseAPIMock()
...
...
@patch('MyModule.DatabaseAPI', my_dbapi)
def my_test(self):
    my_class = MyClass() #<---This is where I'm not able to mock the DatabaseAPI
```

This is what I tried to achieve so far, but from debugging the code I see that the self.dbapi is instantiated with the real object and not with the pre-made mock.

What am I missing?
BTW, we're running python 2.7

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain how you import `DatabaseAPI` in `MyModule`?

Comment: I've completely changed my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're patching the wrong thing. You need to patch in the module that is assigning the attribute, ie the one that contains the target class.

It would be easier if you defined a method in your target class that gets your DatabaseAPI object. That way you can much more easily patch it.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dbapi = self.get_db_api()
        self.timeout = 120

    def get_db_api():
        return DatabaseAPI()
```

and the test becomes:

```
@patch('my_module.MyClass.get_db_api')
def my_test(self, my_method):
    my_method.return_value = my_dbapi
```

Comment: HI Daniel, Thanks for the quick response, It's my fault that I 'skipped' that part, but in my code I actually patch the full class path, including modules. I'll update the question

Comment: Regarding your second recommendation,
We have few hundred of classes written in a similar way to MyClass.
I'm trying to create a single patch decorator that will suit all of them without needing to create a different patch for each test (as the class name changes).
Also, I'd rather not to change the code of those classes unless there won't be any other way.

Comment: I have a similar scenario. I can not change the target class and it internally instantiates a utility class instance, which although can be mocked in the testing class it does not affect what is used inside the target class.  So the above approach does not work

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use

```
@patch('MyModule.DatabaseAPI', return_value=my_dbapi)
```

instead.

In `MyModule` `DatabaseAPI` is something like a factory but `my_dbapi` is a instance. So by set the instance as return value of your factory you mock `self.dbapi` reference.

If in production code you can change the design a little bit consider to move as @DanielRoseman's answer propose: it is a better design.